# "Try it out on more than you" What does it mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I heard a line in the movie [The Humbling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Humbling_(film)):

> Pegeen: We're doing a contemporary adaptation of Macbeth, and I cannot think of another actor. I'd like to try it out on **more than you**.

I can't figure out why the character said **more than you**. I would understand it if the line was *I'd like to try it out on you* (which means "I'd like to have you try the role") But what does the character mean by **more than you**?

Comment: You are parsing it wrong. "(I cannot think of another actor) (I'd like to try it out on more) (than you)."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare the following:

> I can't think of another place I'd like to visit more than it.

We understand that sentence so:

> I can't think of another place I'd like to visit more than [I'd like to visit] it.

That place is at the top of my list of places to visit.

Or this:

> I can't think of another meal I'd like to eat more than it.

which is understood so:

> I can't think of another meal I'd like to eat more than [I'd like to eat] it.

The meal is my favorite meal.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a period where it is not supposed to be because it gives two different meanings. But, if it is not a period, it means there is no one more desirable in her mind that she would rather have try the role. If it is a separate sentence then they are saying that they want to try it out on more people but can't think of anymore actors, which is a weird way to say it so it is probably the first way.